# Internet Explorer 7 strange behaviour for drop down list

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Created a very simple HTML/CSS drop down navigation using nested unordered lists.

Works great with Firefox, Chrome, IE8 but in IE7 the sub navigation doesn't sit below the parent, instead it sits below parent to the right.

For an example and HTML/ CSS have a look here http://webfe.omega.studiocoast.com.au/

I'm stumped!

Comment: Please leave IE7 alone. It is very disturbed and buggy. Talk to IE8 for your work. I say RIP IE7.

Comment: I agree IE7 is buggy and useless however given a large percentage of users still use it, it unfortunately cannot be ignored in the design process

Comment: Not supporting IE7 is good incentive to get people to upgrade ;)

Comment: Haha so everyone has given up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE gets confused by `position: absolute` inside floats with `auto` layout. Set an explicit `left: 0` on `.sub_nav` and `position: relative` on the parent (floated) `li` to avoid this.

(Is `float: left; display:inline-block;` intentional, to work around some other bug or something? It doesn't make sense by itself.)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you muchly :) and the float and inline-block was me trying to hack another bug haha